# Use existing custom domain for API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have created a simple POST method function in Lambda. I have used API Gateway. This API Gateway's endpoint URL is so tricky. So I planned to use a custom domain for API Gateway using Amazon route 53. I already have a domain with SSL in Godaddy. How to use that domain as an API Gateway's endpoint. Do I still need to get ACM? I see that it costs 400$ after the free tier. Please help me out.

```
'use strict';
const dbjs = require('./database/index');
module.exports.signup =async (event) => {
  let user = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const db = await dbjs.get();
  const saveUser = await db.collection('user').insertOne(user)
  return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(saveUser) }
};
```

> serverless deploy

Comment: Public SSL/TLS certificates provisioned through AWS Certificate Manager are free. In your case the above one would be applied. The $400 pricing is If you manage AWS Private Certificate Authority (CA) through ACM .  Follow this article to achieve the same https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-domain-name-amazon-api-gateway/

Comment: Great. Thanks! I know need to pay for Managing hosted zone (AWS Route 53). Can you tell me what are the other pricings comes into the picture if I use the existing domain for API Gateway except for Lambda & Route 53 cost?

Comment: There should be no other cost, unless you choose to use other services.  I have go daddy domains and I map them to a AWS Route53.

Comment: @RodP I have go daddy subdomains and have to map them to AWS Route53. Can you please share how to do it.

Comment: There are a few online tutorials on how to do this.  For example https://tutorialsjoint.com/godaddy-to-route53/.  Much better written and more detailed than I can add in comments here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Serverless Framework, the best-known way of managing custom domains for API Gateway is Serverless Domain Manager plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-domain-manager. In the plugin's readme you will see specific examples on how to setup custom domain for APIGW.